# Debugging ironpython code in SharpDevelop 4.2

Tags: debugging, ironpython, sharpdevelop

I am practising IronPython coding in SharpDevelop 4.2 but I have problems with debugging. In the Locals Window I can't find my variables. In a simple script like this...

```
a=5
b=3
c=8
print c
raw_input('')
```

where in the Locals window can I find the values of a, b and c? Because Locals window is full of information, can I make it presenting only my variables and objects?

Answer (score 2):

Your variables are there in the Watch window just hidden way inside the module's dictionary.

```
$originalModule -> Non-Public members -> _dict_
```

In this dictionary the variables names are in the dictionary **Keys** and the variable values are in the dictionary **Values**.

Currently SharpDevelop does not show this information very well and to fix this will involve changing SharpDevelop's source code.

I would suggest you try [Python Tools for Visual Studio](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) for a better debugging experience. Python Tools for Visual Studio will display your variables in the Watch window at the top level. Python Tools for Visual Studio is free and can be used with the [free Visual Studio Integrated Shell](http://pytools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20-%20details).

Comment: Ok, I downloaded Python Tools for Visual Studio and they seem great but how do I enable the locals window during debugging? I am very new to that.

Comment: Using the full version of Visual Studio 2010 the Locals window, when the debugger is started, is available from the Debug menu under Windows - Locals